# Remove spaces at beginning of line if first non-space character is a letter (Notepad++)

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am using Notepad++ to cleanup some wiki code and would like to do the following: I need to remove all leading spaces from a line but only if the first non-space character is a letter. Here's an example:
Input:

```
    This should be changed
    * This should not be changed
    //This souldn't be changed either
```

Output:

```
This should be changed
    * This should not be changed
    //This souldn't be changed either
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the RegEx find and replace option.

Search for

```
 ^\s*(\w.*)$
```

Replace with

```
\1
```

[image]

Explanation:

The search is:

`^` - Beginning of the line

`\s` - A whitespace character

`*` - 0 or more of them

`(` - Begin a capture group

`\w` - A word character ([a-z] or [A-Z])

`.` - Any character

`*` - 0 or more of them

`)` - End our capture group

`$` - End of the line

Replace with:

`\1` - The contents of the first capture group (Our word character and all characters after that)

Comment: `^\s?(\w.*)$` if I only want to find such lines starting with one space, not those with more spaces or no spaces at their start?

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen Should be fine, but to be sure and if you specifically want just one space, you could use `^\s{1}(\w.*)$` I believe